# Nested CSS targeting with Vue.js & Element-UI

Tags: html, css, vue.js, element-ui

I have some nested elements that I need to apply styles in a project that uses Vue.js and Element-UI.

```
<div slot="left">
 <ul class="other">
  <li class="disabledText">
   <el-input v-model="data.other" type="textarea" :autosize="{ minRows: 4}" :maxlength="3999" :disabled="disSendButton" @change="updateSite('other', data.other)" @blur="data.other=$event.target.value.trim()" />
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

In this instance I will be dynamically applying the class "disabledText" to the li element to color the text in the nested textarea, however I am unable to get the rule in the disabledText class to apply to the text area.

The CSS that I have tried:

```
.disabledText textarea{
    color:red !important;
{

 li.disabledText textarea{
    color:red !important;
{

ul.other li.disabledText textarea{
    color:red !important;
{
```

Even applying a class name directly to the textarea element and referencing that in the CSS class does not have any effect.

The rendered HTML looks like:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctad2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that is gonna work:

`.disabledText .el-textarea`
or
`.disabledText .el-textarea .el-textarea__inner`

Although it's kinda hard to solve this problem without any reproduction. Could you provide an example in CodeSandbox?